# Would it be normal if I used Unity for 3D and Godot for 2D? Is it bad to use multiple?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4, godot

I just wanna ask if it's normal to use multiple game engines for different uses and games.
So basically learning multiple programming languages to use multiple game engines.

Unity: 3D

Unreal: Intense 3D

Godot: 2D

Or do I have to stick to one?

Comment: It's absolutely normal when developing, particularly with a team diverse enough such that previous experience becomes a lesser-factor. However if you're trying to level up your skills , i'd go with unity or godot and make some small, scope managed games (finishing a project is much more important than the project being good when starting out). Unreal is great but I have seen it straight up put people off game dev altogether, so i'd stay well clear of it for now (also let's be real, the 2D support sucks).

Comment: @George Yeah the 2D takes too long for simple things, it's like 2 hours for a snake game. Also your saying it would be fine to learn both Unity and Godot and use Unity for 3D games but Godot for 2D games? I already have programming expirence, with javascript and python and i'm learning flutter and dart. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to develop the same game in 2d, 3d ecc stick to one game engine, if you want to do multiple games you may choose different game engines, in particular the ones that fit your game better. Sticking with one will let you understand it deeply and know all of its faces.

Comment: thanks I might just use unity for 3D